# Tuning query with VARCHAR2 column

Tags: performance, oracle, oracle10g

There is this stored procedure that builds a dynamic query string and then execute it. The sp works *fine* in development and testing environment, but the DBA of the client company has informed that this query is hitting really hard to the database in production. The IT area has asked us to tune up the query. So far so good, we've moved almost all this sp from building the query string dynamically into a single big query that performs really fast (compared to the old query).

We have found (among other things) that the sp built the where clause of the query string by evaluating if a parameter has a default value or a real value i.e.

```
IF P_WORKFLOWSTATUS <> 0 THEN
    L_SQL := TRIM(L_SQL) || ' AND WORKFLOW.STATUS = ' || TO_CHAR(P_WORKFLOWSTATUS);
END IF;
```

So we optimized this behavior to

```
WHERE
    ...
    AND (WORKFLOW.STATUS = P_WORKFLOWSTATUS OR P_WORKFLOWSTATUS = 0)
```

This kind of change has improved the query that affected numeric columns, but we have found a problem with a VARCHAR2 parameter and column. The current behavior is

```
--CLIENT.CODE is a VARCHAR2(14) column and there is an unique index for this column.
--The data stored in this field is like 'N0002077123', 'E0006015987' and similar
IF NVL(P_CLIENT_CODE, '') <> '' THEN
    L_SQL := TRIM(L_SQL) || ' AND CLIENT.CODE = ''' || P_CLIENT_CODE || '''';
END IF;
```

We tried to change this to our *optimized* version of the query by doing

```
WHERE
    ...
    AND (CLIENT.CODE = P_CLIENT_CODE OR NVL(P_CLIENT_CODE, '') = '')
```

but this change made the query lost performance. Is there a way to optimize this part of the query or should we turn our big query into a dynamic query (again) just to evaluate if this `VARCHAR2` parameter should be added or not into the where clause?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: NVL(P_CLIENT_CODE, '') is never equal to '' , because '' is `null` and nothing is equal to `null`. maybe you want p_client_code `is null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend or to move this varchar2 parameters back to dynamic, or to use the following:

```
WHERE
    ...
    AND CLIENT.CODE = nvl(P_CLIENT_CODE,CLIENT.CODE)
```

and be sure you have index on client.code.(Or the table partitioned on client.code, if possible.)

Comment: It makes sense. But I think it would be better to use `coalesce` instead of `nvl` for a couple of reasons: 1) `Nvl` always evaluates both arguments; 2) `Nvl` do an implicit datatype conversion

Comment: I'd go for building the query string dynamically

Comment: @DavidAldridge sure, that's best solution because it has no risks :)

Answer (score 2):

Oracle treats empty strings `''` as NULL. So this condition `NVL(P_CLIENT_CODE, '') = ''` doesn't really make much sense. Moreover it will always be false, because here we are checking equality of NULLs, which is always false. To that end you might and probably should recode that part of the query as:

```
WHERE
    ...
    AND ( (CLIENT.CODE = P_CLIENT_CODE) OR (CLIENT IS NULL) )
```

Comment: @FlorinGhita If columns are indexed appropriately. As `CLIENT` can be NULL - indexed including constant (`create index indx_name on table_name(CLIENT, 1)` for example), then yes it should get a bit better at least for this part.

Comment: @DavidAldrdge yes it does, but it compares the result of the NVL() with = ''. This will never succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, as it has already been said, you need need to perform correct null checks.

However, the trick is, the difference between

```
AND (CLIENT.CODE = P_CLIENT_CODE OR NVL(P_CLIENT_CODE, '') = '')
```

and

```
AND ( (CLIENT.CODE = P_CLIENT_CODE) OR (CLIENT IS NULL) )
```

is very unlikely to cause performance problems only by itself. I would even say that query with second clause could perform *worse* than with the first one, as it will yield true for more rows, resulting in larger result set for consequent joins/orders/filers etc.

I'd bet that adding this clause to your query somehow breaks its optimal execution plan. For instance, having obsolete statistics, the optimizer could make a sub-optimal decision to choose unselective index on `client.code` instead of others available.

However, it is hard to tell for sure without seeing actual (not the expected one, which you obtain with `explain plan` command!) execution plan of slow query and your table structure.